# reledmac: skip newline in eledsection

Tags: sectioning, line-breaking, reledmac

I am trying to skip the newline in a `\eledsection` but both `\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[runin]{}{}{}{}[]` and `\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=-.5\baselineskip,afterskip=-1em]{section}` do not work. With titlesec it won't even compile, the other solution gives me overlapping text:

```
\documentclass[paper=b5,fontsize=12pt,twoside=semi]{scrbook}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\Xarrangement[A]{twocol}
\linenummargin{inner}
\firstlinenum{5}
\linenumincrement{5}
\date{}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
   beforeskip=-.5\baselineskip,
   afterskip=-1em]{section}
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\normalsize}
\addtokomafont{section}{\normalsize}
\begin{document}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\eledchapter{Chapter}
\pend 
\pstart 
\eledsection{Test}
\pend  
\pstart 
Testtext 
\pend  
\endnumbering
\end{document}
```

produces:

[image]

Has anyone got any ideas how to solve that?

Comment: unfortunately, that is a limit of the implemtation of `\eledsection`. It can't deal with the particular implementation of `\section`. Do you really need eledsection feature, with line numbering ?

Comment: I do. I actually would need to use \edtext within \eledsection* which does not work either for some reason. So maybe I have to find a workaround anyway?

Comment: a workaround could be to add negative vspace in the optional argument of \pend